# The division operation of overloaded function operators leads to the change of divisor

Tags: c++

when I build a class named "Money", I overloaded the "/" sign in the class. But the divisor changed during the division operation. As  shown below:

(1.This is the declaration of overloaded function operators in the header file）

```
Money& operator/(double);
void division(double);
```

（2.This is the specific definition of overloaded operator）

```
void Money::division(double i)
{
money_number = money_number / i;
}


Money& Money::operator/(double i)
{
division(i);
return *this;
}
```

（3.This is my call to it in the main function）

```
Money money_temp=100;
Money mmm = 0;
cout <<"mmm" << money_temp << endl;
mmm = money_temp / 2;
cout << "mmm" << money_temp << endl;
```

But I found that in the end “money_temp” changed after division.
it became 50 from 100.
I try to delete the "&" in the "Money& operator/(double);" , but I failed.

How to resolve this problem? Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You're modifying it when you call `Money::division` through the operator. Create a copy of your object and use that one instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

In `Money::division` you're modifying the object through the statement `money_number = money_number / i;`, which assigns a new value to `money_number`.

**Solution:**

Create a copy of the object in the division and return that instead.

**Code:**

```cpp
Money Money::operator/(double i)
{
    Money temp = money_number / i;
    return temp;
}
```

Note that I deleted the `&` because it would lead to a dangling reference otherwise.